# Clarification on the SVD of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

Given a matrix $G$, let its singular value decomposition be

$$G = Y \Sigma U^H$$

In the Hermitian matrix $G^H = U \Sigma Y^H$, why doesn't $\Sigma ^H$ appear instead of $\Sigma$?

If $G$ is a complex matrix, its singular values should be complex. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Singular values are always real and nonnegative even when the entries are complex. In fact if you already know that they are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^H A$, then the result follows from the simple observation $\| Ax \|^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: Can you suggest me where I can found a proof? Thanks

Comment: Trefethen and Bau is my preferred reference but really anything on the SVD will elaborate on this.